# jQuery - Using .offset and translateX to bypass css wrapper causing random whitespace

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design, offset

I have a page with a content wrapper set to max-width 1280 and automatic margins. I am trying to create a jQuery script that calls all divs with the class "full-width", changes their css width to the full width of the window, and adds a negative translateX value to make them flush with the left side of the window.

The script works perfectly on load, but offset does not appear to be updating correctly on window resize. This is causing random amounts of white space to appear on the left or the right of the "full-width" divs.

```
var responsive = function () {
var offset = $('.full-width').offset();
$('.full-width').css({
'width':($(window).width())+'px',
'transform': 'translateX(-' + offset.left + 'px)',
'-webkit-transform': 'translateX(-' + offset.left + 'px)',
'-moz-transform': 'translateX(-' + offset.left + 'px)',
'-ms-transform': 'translateX(-' + offset.left + 'px)'
});
};

$(document).ready(responsive);
$(window).resize(responsive);
```

Answer (score 0):

The jquery offset() function does not take transform into account when computing the offset, which I believe (but without an jsfiddle or codepen I couldn't be sure) is your problem.  Perhaps you want to use position:relative and set the left of the selectors?  I don't know exactly what you are doing, but usually this can be done completely in CSS and you may be overly complicating things (plus adding lots of overhead with the resize function being called multiple times every time the user resizes the page) by using jQuery to do your responsive sizing.